Having trouble with Guppy Animation Tools for Maya 2024
I am trying to get Guppy Animation Tools to work for Maya 2024, but I cant get it to work. I have the guppy_animation_tools folder in my maya/2024/scripts folder as well as the userSetup.py, but when I got at run cleverKeys.setKey(), i get this:
#Error: NameError: file  line 1: name 'cleverKeys' is not defined
I dont think that the userSetup.py is running when maya starts.
